# Making bash work via website

Tags: ubuntu, scripting

Hi I'm trying to have a script in a site (probably using PHP) that runs a command in a screen. Note this screen is note located in the website files, on the same server in the /home directory.

So is there a way by a click of a button on this php page I could.

- Stop the current program in the screen (usually done by pressing <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd>)
- run a bash command (`bash /home/fx2/run.sh +exec server.cfg`)
- This bash command will start a game server back up.

So is all that possible?

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand what you mean by "screen".  Generally, yes you can execute bash from php using the tic operator. However you may need to add references to your php files in the sudoers config, but that all depends on what your bash is doing.

http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.execution.php

Comment: The bash script is to restart a game server which is in a screen on the server.

Comment: Do you mean that the console is outputting to monitor or that the game is being displayed on some kind of digital sign?  Either way that shouldn't matter.  Add your php script to sudoers and give the back-tic operator a try.

Comment: https://serverfault.com/questions/772171/allowing-php-to-run-specific-bash-script-with-root-permissions

Comment: I mean screen as in https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-and-use-screen-on-an-ubuntu-cloud-server

But I have no clue on how to do this through a site.

Comment: Gotcha.  Screen will not be relevant to php when it is sending bash commands.  In other words, screen is for people ... back tic is for php.

Comment: Thanks for the reply so would I need to have a login or something because the bash file is not in the website files but in a different directory. Also when running this bash the game server would need to be turned off. It also has to be in a cd /home/fx2/server-data/

Comment: You do not have to be in the same dir to run bash from php.  You can use relative or absolute paths.  It's mostly a matter of linux permission.  You should probably make a linux user group so that everything can play together nicely.